# Match numbers without dot at the start

Tags: javascript, regex

This RegEXP match a number with decimal separator:

```
(?=\D?)([1-9][0-9]{1,2})\.(\d+)(?=\D?)
```

I want it exclude this one cuz it has a dot at the start.

.999.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/(?:^|[^.])\b([1-9][0-9]{1,2})\.(\d+)\b/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uO8hO1/1)

`(?:^|[^.])` will match either line start or any character other than `DOT` before your number.